# If a polynomial $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ that cannot be divided by the square of an irreducible polynomial. Is it true that $I(V(f))=(f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

First of all, for an ideal $J$ of the ring $ k[x_1,...,x_n]$, and for a subset $X \subseteq k^n$, we define:

- $V(J) = \{ P \in k^n : f(P)=0 \ \ \ \forall \ f \in J\}$
- $I(X) = \{f \in  k[x_1,...,x_n] : f(P) = 0 \ \ \ \forall \ P \in X$

I know that $I(V(f))=\sqrt{(f)}$, according to Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. So, the question is: Is it true that $\sqrt{(f)} = (f)$, considering that the polynomial $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ cannot be divided by the square of an irreducible polynomial ? 
It would suffice to show that the ideal $(f)$ is prime or maximal, but I can't find a proof for that. 
Also, I should mention that $\sqrt{(f)} = \{g \in k[x_1,...,x_n] : \exists \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \text{such that} \ \ g^n \in (f) \} $. 
Any help would would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the radical of $(f)$ is generated by its square-free sibling (i.e. take its irreducible factorization and set exponent of factors to 1).  This follows easily from considering which polynomials $g$ can have powers that are divisible by $f$.

Comment: I didn't quite get the last part, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you know what a unique factorization domain is?  Do you know that due to Hilbert's basis theorem the ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a unique factorization domain?  So what can you tell about the irreducible factors of $g$ if a power of $g$ is divisible by $f$?  If this is confusing, work in the integers (also a UFD).  If a power of integer $g$, say $g^n$ is divisible by an integer $f$, what does that tell us about the prime factors of $g$ in relation to the prime factors of $f$?

Comment: That's clearer now, thanks!